# In Android programming, how do I carry a variable from a button press to my main program?

Tags: android

How would one set the button1 variable to true in the ReadButtons method and have it be used in the onCreate method/class?

I am a noob and have spent many hours trying to figure this out. I have no idea where to look for the answer any further. I know I may be way off in my understanding of how this works. But I don't know how to correct that misunderstanding. My background is in C and other procedural programming languages. Thank you kindly for your help.

```
package com.test;

// This is being run on Eclipse Helios with ADK set to Android 2.2 
// and a 10 inch landscape display tablet PC.

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.lang.Boolean;

public class ButtonTestActivity extends Activity {


    public static Boolean button1 = false, button2 = false;
    public static String myText="Drat";

    TextView textV_Test_Display;

    public void ReadButtons(){
        Button btn_button1_Ref = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_button1);
        btn_button1_Ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myText="YAY!";
                button1 = true;

                // if(button1) textV_Test_Display.setText(myText);
                //
                // When I uncomment the above, it works as I desire visually.
                // 
                // How do I set button1=true here and have 
                // the value carry back to the onCreate class?
                //
                //
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });


        Button btn_button2_Ref = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_button2);
        btn_button2_Ref.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myText="WOOT!";
                button2 = true;

                // if(button2) textV_Test_Display.setText(myText);
                //
                // When I uncomment the above, it works as I desire visually.
                // 
                // How do I set button2=true here and have 
                // the value carry back to the onCreate class?
                //
                //
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Button 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textV_Test_Display = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtV_ID_Test_Data);    

        ReadButtons();

        if(button1 || button2) textV_Test_Display.setText(myText);
        // This does not display myText.
        // I am not able to carry the button1 or button2 variables to 
        // this part of the program.

        // textV_Test_Display.setText(myText);
        // When uncommented, this displays the word "Drat".
        // When commented out, the word "nope" is displayed.        
        // In the main.xml file the text is set to the word "nope"
        // This tells me this command works as expected.

        }
    }
```

This is the main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FF000FFF" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:height="50dp" 
        android:text="Button 1" 
        android:width="140dp" 
        android:textSize="16dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="220dp"></Button>



    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:height="50dp" 
        android:text="Button 2" 
        android:width="140dp" 
        android:textSize="16dp" 
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="450dp"></Button>



    <TextView android:id="@+id/txtV_ID_Test_Data"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28dp" 
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:typeface="sans" 
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp" 
        android:height="50dp"
        android:width="120dp" 
        android:text="nope" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="338dp"
        android:background="#F00FF0F0"

    ></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You are setting button1 = true in the onClick event. To be honest your code is pretty strange, I would take a look at some tutorials to see the correct way to do things in OO programming.

Comment: Yes, I am setting button1 = true in the onclick event. That is the point. I then want to evaluate the variable button1 in the onCreate method.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. 1. Yes, I am setting button1 = true in the onclick event. That is the point. I then want to evaluate the variable button1 in the onCreate method. 2. I have spent the last 4 months studying java and android programing books and many hours watching video tutorials. All but one (bhecker.com) assumes an advanced level of Java programming skill. 3. To risk blatantly showing my ignorance, I am assuming that the onCreate method is the "main" calling program that calls the ReadButton method. If this is incorrect, what do I need to understand instead? Thank you.

Comment: Look at the Activity life cycle - onCreate is just method executed **ONCE** when activity is created. It's not executed after pressing button, so obviously - there is no possibility to evaluate variable set in OnClickListener in onCreate() method. Execute your actions in onClick() methods.

Answer (score 1):

there is a couple of problems here.

1. You are setting the button to true in the listener, but that code will not be executed until the button is clicked.
2. you are trying to read the button1&button2 values in the on create *method* but so this code executes before the code in you listeners have exectued (because they haven't been clicked)

It look like you want to display some text based on weather either button is clicked: SO do this

make an update method

```
public void update() {
    if(button1 || button2) textV_Test_Display.setText(myText);
}
```

called update() after you have set your variables in the button listener.

Comment: logically ReadButtons() is misnamed - it should be setupButtons()

Comment: also it look like you are new, don't forget to award points if you want more questions answered ;)

Comment: I removed this response. I am still learning how to use this forum. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. 1. I do not want the button1=true code to execute until the button is pushed. Then, in the main program I want to evaluate which button has been pressed. 2. In my ignorance I am assuming that the onCreate method continues to run as the "main program" calling the subroutine (method) ReadButtons. Forgive my ignorance, but do I need a main method to call all of these other methods? Thank you.

Comment: no there is no main method - Android has numerous lifecycle method that the system calls. onCreate is called when the activity is first created (only) . onStart is called every time the activity comes to the foreground. Read the activity lifecycle page :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html